# How to read a file line by line in java with the line number

Tags: java, filereader, split

I want to read a file in java line by line. For example I have a file as new.txt

new.txt

```
Log points: 

1.  We develop a project about Preventive Maintenance Checklist for Employees on PC/Tablet using Java.
2.  We here have check boxes for checking the list of works for quarterly, half yearly and annually.
3.  This tool is created to check the lists.
4.  This tool is created to make no human errors
5.  This tool is created using eclipse development tool.
6.  Eclipse is an IDE – Integrated development environment.
7.  Eclipse is a java development tool with many plug-ins and supports.
8.  We use WAMP server as database server which hosts the database connectivity.
9.  The database is created using the Mysql. Mysql is free source tool for creating database.
10.  The project has a user interface which is created using JSP –Java server pages.
11.  Jsp is used for user interface designing and it is compiled in java compiler.
12.  Servlets are server side scripting. Which accepts client side requests from the jsp and it connects with the business logic and gives the response.
13. Our application runs in Apache tom cat server. It is free server developed and released by apache software foundation.
14. This server is hosts the application and run.
15. In our project we give request from the jsp and we give the defined values to the servlets which runs in the server. The servlets takes the response and gives the expected output. 
16. The values are stored in the database. And can be retrieved and deleted in future.
17. This project gives the complete information and logs the information provided.
18. We used MIRRA ,DNS, Sort and merge, profiler.
19.  We also logs the time starts and time ends and it schedules that way.
20. We also logs the output, issues, action required etc.
```

Now I will read based on the line number. And want to write it in a new file. For example from line 1-3 in file f1.txt and line 3-6 f2.txt. I know to write in another file. But doesn't know how to split it in java.

```
 BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while(br.readLine()!=null)
        {
        String s=br.readLine();


        counter++;
        }


        int size=counter/9;

            System.out.println(counter);

       for(int id=0;id<size;id++)
       {

           //how to split the files and read And from here no idea
       }
```

Comment: I have edited with code. help me.

Comment: Use Apache Common IO FileUtil http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get some idea from this. This is not a very good solution but you can get some idea from this

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new File("/home/ruchira/Test.txt"));
FileWriter fileWriter1=new FileWriter(new File("/home/ruchira/1.txt"));
// you will have to create more files. 
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line=scanner.nextLine();
    int lineNum=0;
    try {
        if(!line.equals("")){
            lineNum=Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\.")[0]);
            if(lineNum>=1 && lineNum<=3){ // check for line numbers
                fileWriter1.append(line) ;
                fileWriter1.append("\n");
            }
            // there will be more if conditions in your case.
        }

    }catch (NumberFormatException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e){

    }

}
fileWriter1.close();
```